# confusing TcpMaxDataRetransmissions

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

I am confusing with TcpMaxDataRetransmissions parameter in windows.

Accounding to this [page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780586%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), TcpMaxDataRetransmissions means that the times that windows will retransmit for an un-acked packet.

The default value in windows 2003 is 5.

But Why I see 8 retransmission times in a wireshark sniffer file?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved, 5 works. Windows server retransmission one packet at most 5 times by default.

Note the pmtu(len 524 packets), do not include that 'five times'